# React - Passing Data to Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, components

I'm trying to understand how I can pass data from container to component. Right now I have a list of transactions in reducer, transactions sum is calculated in container and currently it is being displayed in the container. How do I pass my calculations to component and display it from there?

Code below is shortened to make it easier to read.

reducer:

```
const transactions = [
  {
    amount: 2,
  },
  {
    amount: 1,
  },
]
```

container:

```
@connect(state => ({
  transactions: state.transactions,
}))

export default class Bank extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Balance amount={ this.props.transactions.reduce((sum, nextElement) => sum + nextElement.amount, 0)}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

component:

```
const Balance = ({ amount }) => (
  <div>
    {amount}
  </div>
)
```

Any help would be highly appreciated :)

Comment: You are passing the calculated amount through to the Balance Component as a prop and displaying it there already, so not sure what your problem is?

Comment: @RobWalker the problem is that my amount is displayed in container, and component displays "0". it seems like it does not path calculated amount, and i'm not sure why

Comment: this looks correct

Answer (score 0):

Seems likely an issue with how your store is setup or with how your global state is being set. I would use redux dev tools to examine your state because your reduction is correct and you're passing in the prop correctly to your child component.

Comment: This could probably be a comment instead of an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I belive you have to pass this.state.transactions instead props and initiallize the amount state in your class Balance calling like amount = this.props.amout